# DNA Matching LISP

Tags: list, lisp

I am currently trying to use LISP to make a function that looks at DNA pairs and returns either `T` or `NIL` depending on if they match or not

Logically I know you need to go through the different possible cases recursively, but am just not quite sure how to do this in LISP.  I would appreciate any help you can provide.

I know that I now need to go through and compare A to T, and C to G, but I have no clue how to do this.

EDIT: Test cases to show what I mean more clearly

```
(dnamatching '(a t c g) '(a c g g))
==> NIL
(dnamatching '(a a t c g) '(t t a g c))
==> T
```

Comment: could you please add some test cases? e.g., what lists would match and which would not.

Comment: @sds There you go, hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Here is a basic version

```
(defun dnamatch-1 (x y)
  (ecase x
    ((a) (eq y 't))
    ((t) (eq y 'a))
    ((c) (eq y 'g))
    ((g) (eq y 'c))))

(defun dnamatch-list (a b)
  (every #'dnamatch-1 a b))

(dnamatch-list '(a t c g) '(a c g g))
==> NIL
(dnamatch-list '(a a t c g) '(t t a g c))
==> T
```

If you prefer, here is an iterative version instead:

```
(defun dnamatch-list (a b)
  (loop for x in a and y in b
    always (dnamatch-1 x y)))
```

#### Documentation:

- [`every`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm)
- [`ecase`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_case_.htm)
- [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm): [`for`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abab.htm) and [`always`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ad.htm)

## Notes

#### [nucleobase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleobase) representation

You are using the standard constant [`t`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_t.htm) as name for a nucleobase, which is probably not the best approach.
You might want to use [characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_ch.htm) (`#\t` &c) or longer symbols (`thymine` &c) instead.
If you decide to use characters, you might want to use [strings](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_string.htm) instead of [lists](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_list.htm).

#### Error checking

Note that my `dnamatch-1` checks that `x` contains only valid symbols but does not check `y`.

#### length checking

Both versions of `dnamatch-list` only compare the shortest common part of its arguments, you probably would want to do something like

```
(defun dnamatch-list (a b)
  (and (= (length a) (length b))
       (every #'dnamatch-1 a b)))
```

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the reversing question. if you want to match the first nucleobase of the first dna against the last nucleobase of the second dna, then, yes, you need to use reverse as you suggested.

Comment: The `MAPCAR` in the first one is unnecessary, since `EVERY` can take multiple lists as arguments, so `(every #'dnamatch-1 a b)` should work.